# How can I solve a gdal problem in R and Ubuntu?

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio, gdal, rgdal

I'm working on Ubuntu with Rstudio to work with raster and TIFF images, and for that I need to use the following function:

```
mosaic_rasters(gdalfile=all_my_rasts,dst_dataset=paste0(ruta_mosaico, "/", "mosaic.tif"), of="GTiff")
```

However, I keep getting the following error repeatedly:

```
Error in gdal_chooseInstallation(hasDrivers = of) : 
  No installations match.
```

I am using the following versions of the libraries.

```
gdal-config --versiom -> 3.3.2
R --version -> R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15) -- "Shortstop Beagle"
```

I have reinstalled everything, tried almost everything that I have found on the internet, but I can't seem to solve it.

I have tried changing the version, reinstalling gdal, installing everything from scratch... but I always end up with the same problem.